# Opportunity is not getting mapped to Account in Screen flow

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity, account, salesforce-id, field-mapping

I have created a screen flow in which I am trying to create an Opportunity automatically mapped to the Account and I have placed it in the account detail page.

I have added the resource named recordId too and mapped it to AccountId of Opportunity in the create record component, as the associated account ID will automatically get passed to the recordId variable from Account detail page.

But when I enter the Opportunity details and click on create, the Opportunity is getting created, but it is not getting mapped to respective Account. Can anyone please let me know why the record isn't getting mapped.

Below is the image of my mapping in create record element.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have followed the below steps:

1. Marking the `recordId` as required in the flow:

[image]

2. While adding the flow to app builder, check the **Pass `recordId` into this variable** to the appropriate flow variable.

[image]

Comment: I had missed the last step! where we have to check the pass record ID into this variable. It worked perfectly now. Thank you.